# Doing a common operation before entering all methods of a class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to perform a common operation before entering the method and right after leaving the method. The class is huge and i do not want to duplicate code all over the place. Is there any pattern i can use or a specific construct that could help me here.

Comment: "*The class is huge*" you may want to refactor it. If you have so many methods that adding a single method call to perform this common operation at the top of each method is too much trouble, the class probably needs to be broken down anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have huge classes. I would suggest refactoring and representing each method as a Command object.

You can also use aspects to perform tasks in the desired manner. Look at frameworks like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net).

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical case of AOP (aspect oriented programming). AOP is for doing operations that cut across the methods/classes/packages. See [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288717%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers gives you good advices and practices to follow, but if you can't do the refactor and you are ok about using reflection, you can do the following.

Create a wrapper class that wraps your `HugeClass`, including two methods with the *common operations* you need to do *before* and *after* the method invocation, and expose a method to invoke any of the wrapped class methods together with the common operations:

```
public static class HugeClassWrapper
{
    private static HugeClass hugeClass = new HugeClass();

    public static void Invoke(Expression<Action<HugeClass>> expression)
    {
        CommonOperationBefore();    
        expression.Compile().Invoke(hugeClass); 
        CommonOperationAfter();
    }

    public static TResult Invoke<TResult>(Expression<Func<HugeClass, TResult>> expression)
    {
        CommonOperationBefore();    
        TResult result = (TResult)expression.Compile().Invoke(hugeClass);
        CommonOperationAfter();
        return result;
    }

    private static void CommonOperationBefore()
    {
        // your common operations...
    }
    private static void CommonOperationAfter()
    {
        // your common operations...
    }
}
```

I've included two overloads of the `Invoke` method, and the reason is to be able to call void methods or methods that returns any value.

So, for example, if your class is:

```
public class HugeClass
{
    public string Method1(int a, double b)
    {
        return (a * b).ToString();
    }
    // ...
    public void Method1000()
    {
    }
}
```

In order to invoke the methods, you can do this:

```
string result = HugeClassWrapper.Invoke<string>(x => x.Method1(2, 3.14));
```

or

```
HugeClassWrapper.Invoke(x => x.Method1000());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at aspect-oriented programming such as:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288717(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-
  PostS
- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/09/01/aop-with-postsharp.aspx

Essentially, using AOP framework like PostSharp injects code at the beginning and end as you mention, and this can be dynamic or static, all by applying an attribute like this:

```
[ExceptionHandler]
  public void CreateError() {
    .
    .
  }
```

Where ExceptionHandler is a custom attribute you create.  Some frameworks intercept the method call and run some code, [like SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Interception).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, even if it seems not to be to you right now. Some things to look into are [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and [interception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern).